# Tk window layout , widget size to maximize

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I am trying to create a window in tcl , by using the TK package.

The window consists of 4 text widget and a menubar.

(like this: http://artafact.be/sites/default/files/window.png )

But I want the window to be maximazed to the screen.

I tried to do this by:

`set widthsmall  [expr {int([winfo screenwidth  .] * 0.25)}]`

     ....

`text .main \
             -width $widthsmall -height $heightbig \`

but this gives as results a window that is wider then the screen!

How is this possible?

```
proc buildUI {} {
    global widthsmall
    global widthbig
    global heightsmall
    global heightbig
    frame .toolbar
    scrollbar .vsb -command [list .main yview]
    text .main \
        -width $widthsmall -height $heightbig \
        -yscrollcommand [list .vsb set] \
        -highlightthickness 0
   scrollbar .vsb1 -command [list .test yview]
    text .test \
        -width $widthbig -height $heightbig \
        -yscrollcommand [list .vsb1 set] \
        -highlightthickness 0

    scrollbar .vsb2 -command [list .tsvf yview]
    text .tsvf \
        -width $widthsmall -height $heightsmall \
        -yscrollcommand [list .vsb2 set] \
        -highlightthickness 0

    scrollbar .vsb3 -command [list .tobsw yview]
    text .tobsw \
        -width $widthbig -height $heightsmall \
        -yscrollcommand [list .vsb3 set] \
        -highlightthickness 0

    button .b -text start -command start_sim
    pack .b -in .toolbar -side left

    grid .toolbar -sticky nsew -column 0 -row 0 -columnspan 2
    grid .main .vsb  -sticky nsew -column 0 -row 1
    grid .test .vsb1  -sticky nsew -column 1 -row 1
    grid .tsvf .vsb2  -sticky nsew -column 0 -row 2
    grid .tobsw .vsb3 -sticky nsew -column 1 -row 2
}
```

Comment: Your question lacks code, we can hardly guess. How do you pack or grid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To maximize a window whose name is in the variable `win`, use

```
wm state $win zoomed
```

on Windows and Mac OS X, or

```
wm attributes $win -zoomed 1
```

on an X11 system.

To make widgets inside the window expand to match the increased size of the window, configure the geometry manager for expansion.

```
pack .mywidget -expand 1 -fill both ;# grow in both x and y
pack .mywidget -expand 1 -fill x    ;# grow in x
pack .mywidget -expand 1 -fill y    ;# grow in y

grid rowconfigure    . .mywidget -weight 1 ;# this row will expand
grid columnconfigure . .mywidget -weight 1 ;# this column will expand
```

Documentation: [grid](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/grid.htm), [pack](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/pack.htm), [wm](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/wm.htm)

Comment: The text fields height and width in the window will bypass that call

Comment: @user1104939: the text widgets won't be involved in this. You use this invocation to maximize the main window (`.`) or the toplevel window that you are using. You can let the geometry manager set the sizes of the widgets in the maximized windows or set those sizes yourself.

Comment: But it still wouldnt fix that the text widgets wont resize with the window. I want the 2 left widgets (as you can see in the original post) to be 1/4 of the window at all time.

Comment: @user1104939: see updated answer. Is it something like this you are asking for?